# Passing post parameters to action methods in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm new to asp.net mvc. I'm having some trouble getting the values of parameters in my Action methods.

I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ToggleRecommend(string mode)
{
    byte[] requestContent = new byte[Request.ContentLength];
    Request.InputStream.Read(requestContent, 0, Request.ContentLength);
    string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(requestContent);

    return EmptyResult();
}
```

I access this method using an Ajax request. The request has these headers:

```
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  8
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host    localhost:62718
Referer http://localhost:62718/microsite
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
X-Request   JSON
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

and this body:

```
mode=off
```

My problem is that the `mode` parameter of `ToggleRecommend` is not being populated with the value from the request - instead, it is null.

The request is reaching my server correctly: the variable `content` in the method has the value `mode=off` and `Request.ContentLength` is 8 as expected. Also, `Request.RequestType` is "POST", as is intended. However, `Request.Form` is empty: it has no keys or values. (I don't know if that is relevant).

What is going wrong here? How do I get the value of my `mode` parameter to go into my action method?

The problem must be to do with post: If I remove the `HttpPost` attribute and do a request to the Url `localhost:62718/microsite/toggleRecommend/?mode=off` the `mode` parameter gets the value `off` as is intended.

Edit:

The request is being made with javascript using the Mootools library. I've included that part of the code below:

```
var req = new Request.JSON({ method: "post",
        url: "/microsite/toggleRecommend/" ,
        autoCancel: true, urlEncoded: false, secure: false,
        onFailure: recommendFail, onException: recommendFail,
        onSuccess: recommendSuccess
    });

    req.send({ data: { mode: 'on'} });
```

Using firebug, I can see the exact format of the request (and that looks fine) so hopefully the specifics of the javascript code doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't know much about raw HTTP, but with `Accept=application/json`, shouldn't the body of the request be formatted in JSON?

Comment: @dbaseman I'm not certain either, but I think that that header specifies what kind of data should be returned - the action method is supposed to return JSON.

Comment: oh, sorry -- as you mentioned, the problem must be that you're making a GET instead of POST request.

Comment: @dbaseman I don't think it is that, the `RequestType` property is `POST`.

Comment: what's making this request, js?

Comment: Your ajax call content/type is text/html, you need to specify to your controller that you are sending application/json information, otherwise he receives the info, but doesn't know how to distribute it to it's params.

Comment: @Bardo Thanks, that was it. I also had to change my js so that the content was `{mode='off'}` so that it was a javascript object. I wonder why pure text is not valid?

Comment: Easy, mvc uses a specific class to parse json objects to binded elements on the controller, that class is called when the data received is identified as JSON data, if you pass plain text the controller consider it as a simple string and never calls that class.

Comment: @Bardo maybe you could post your comment as an answer, so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call content/type is text/html, you need to specify to your controller that you are sending application/json information, otherwise he receives the info, but doesn't know how to distribute it to it's params